# Process rar file with awk

Tags: bash, awk, rar

I have a 1.5TB database extract from a single table. It was broken up into 7 files and compressed with RAR.

I wanted to extract a subset of the fields into another file for processing.

The examples I have found process bzip or gzip files. Is what I am asking about possible? If not directly how to convert the files to a format that does work with awk?

I have ~146GB of working space on Centos6.

Comment: it's a proprietary format, first you need an extraction software that runs on your OS.  `awk` works on text files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [unrar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar) and then piping the result to `awk`.

For example: let's suppose that you need the last field:

```
unrar p *.rar | awk '{print $NF}'
```

or more efficiently:

```
find . -name *.rar | xargs -n 1 -P 4 unrar p | awk '{print $NF}'
```

The option p means "print file to stdout".

I hope this can help you.